# Comparison of <init> using Regex in perl

Tags: perl

I am extracting line by line from a file and splitting into words.
I want all the words except the words enclosed between '<' and '>'.

```
        if($word =~ m/^(\<).*(\>)$/)
            {
                 print "Remove this word";
            }
```

I tried the above code.But its not working.

This is the file I'm processing :

```
#> main bcel_coverage.A    
#> <init> bcel_coverage.C
<# <init>
   ?? main
abc
<# main
```

I do not want `<init>` in the above file to be printed. Anything else can also be enclosed within '<' and '>'.

Comment: What is it doing instead, and can you show the inputs, pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line with a regex that matches words enclosed inside `<...>`.

```
% perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; $line = "ss<a>s<da>fg"; @words = split(/<[^>]+>/, $line); print Data::Dumper::Dumper( @words );'

$VAR1 = 'ss';
$VAR2 = 's';
$VAR3 = 'fg';
```

Regex:

```
< :    Match starting <
[^>] : Anything that is not >
> :    Closing >
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne '$_=~s/<[^>^<]*>//g; print' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
#> main bcel_coverage.A    
#> <init> bcel_coverage.C
<# <init>
   ?? main
abc
<# main
> perl -ne '$_=~s/<[^>^<]*>//g; print' temp
#> main bcel_coverage.A    
#>  bcel_coverage.C
<# 
   ?? main
abc
<# main
>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. But I'll give Vikas the right answer as he answered it first. Thank you Sarathi.